# В каких случаях нужно использовать самопереадресацию?

Tags: php

Привет.Интересует когда нужно использовать  самопереадресацию?
Буду рад разделам книг,отдельным статейкам или практическими мини примерами.

Comment: чет я вообще ни въехал. Может типа сайт переехал и го сразу?

Comment: @koza4ok, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы.

Comment: "Самопереадресация" - не более чем прием опустошения пришедших post-данных, в некоторых извращенных случаях - способ получить куки "сразу" после их установки. Неужели об этом стоит писать книги?

Comment: На мой взгляд вы не верно обобщили. Вы назвали все варианты реализации самопереадресации извращенными на премере самого извращенного.  ))

Чаще всего самопереадресация нужна для очистки POST-данных. Например скрипт гостевой книги. Если POST-данных нет, то он выводит сообщения. А если POST-данные есть, то сохраняет пришедшие данные, а после переадресуется на себя, чтобы очистить POST-данные. 

Также происходит защита от повторной отправки формы.

Вполне уместное и хорошее применение.

Comment: Она может быть использована помимо очистки ПОСТ для передачи серверу различных сведений о клиенте, которые можно собрать при помощи ЯваСкрипт:  
Включены ли куки и сам Ява Скрипт, есть ли поддержка DOM, размер экрана итп. Собранные данные отправляются в параметрах переадресации и клиенту выводится адаптированная для него версия сайта.